# How to query if a field value of a MongoDB occurs in another field value as a string?

Tags: mongodb

I have another question regarding Mongo DB Queries.
My collections looks like this for example:

```
{"$firstname": 'Max',
"$lastname": 'Mustermann',
"$content": 'Max Mustermann leidet unter Kopfschmerzen'}

{"$firstname": 'Marina',
"$lastname": 'Musterfrau',
"$content": 'Patientin leidet unter Kopfschmerzen'}
```

And now i want to query the **$content** where the values of **$firstname** and **$lastname** occur in the **$content** which would only give me the collection of Max Mustermann.

Background is that i need to gather the text data from **$content** and check if there is sensible data in there like the name, the birthday or anything like this. If it does contain sensible data is there a way to anonymize those parts of the text? If not i would just leave those ones out where the query is true e.g. the **$content** contains sensible data.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trick using [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.huihoo.com/mongodb/3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/index.html).

This operator returns `-1` if the substring is not found. So you can create a new field which store the position where the index has been found.

Creating two fields (for example `existsFirstname` and `existsLastname`), if both are differents than `-1` it means the both substrings exists into `$content` value.

You can use this query using aggregation.

First stage to add the new fields:

- `existsFirstname`: Uses `$indexOfCP` to search the `$firstname`value into `$content`.
- `existsLastname` do the same but using `$lastname`.

Second stage match documents where the two last fields are different than `-1` (i.e. both fields exists into `$content`)

Third stage to remove values into the output.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "existsFirstname": { "$indexOfCP": [ "$content", "$firstname" ] },
      "existsLastname": { "$indexOfCP": [ "$content", "$lastname" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [ 
        { "existsFirstname": { "$ne": -1 } }, 
        { "existsLastname": { "$ne": -1 } } ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "existsFirstname": 0,
      "existsLastname": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OesCLCP_XsW)

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped a lot! Could you also tell me what do i have to do if I want to do this for two collections ? E.g: if we have one Collection text with the attribute $content and one collection patient with the attributes $firstname & $lastname? Sorry i should have wrote this in the question before as well.